# Как вывести JSON без сортировки с сохранением ключей?

Tags: javascript, json

По API получаю данные в таком виде:

```
let ajax = '{"3":{"name":"test 3"},"1":{"name":"test 1"},"2":{"name":"test 2"}}';
```

Читал, что json автоматически сортируется, но мне нужно вывести в том порядке в котором получаю данные

```
test 3
test 1
test 2
```

Можно ли как то решить данный вопрос?

И самое важное сохранить ключи так как по ним идет обращение, в очень многих местах в таком виде `data[searchId]`

```js
let data = {
 "3": {"name": "test 3"},
 "1": {"name": "test 1"},
 "2": {"name": "test 2"},
}

for (let i in data) {
   document.querySelector('.list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data[i].name +'<br>');
}

let searchId = "2";

console.log(data[searchId]);
```

```html
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: нет, не получится так. можно конечно спарсить это, перестроить в нужном формате и выводить..... а какой смысл выводить в том виде в котором написано в API?

Comment: Если это ваш апи - то самое время быстро переделать

Comment: @Алексей, нет, к сожалению не мой api

Comment: окей, а в чём смысла  выводить в том виде в котором представлен объект? на каком месте затык?

Comment: нужно вывести только в одном месте на сайте в нужном порядке в котором данные, я уже нашел решение вытянуть нужные значения при помощи регулярного выражения. Правда этот код у меня выглядит как огромный костыль)

Comment: по-другому и не будет

Comment: передавайте в ответе порядок ключей, например `{ data: {"3": {}, "1": []}, keys: ["3", "1"] }`

Comment: Ну или можно поискать какой-нибудь поточный парсер JSON… Но в целом, просто надавать по голове автору такого JSON-а. Если порядок важен, то должен быть массив.

Comment: @Grundy а что не понятно в вопросе?

Comment: @EzioMercer, действительно ли нужна сортировка именно объекта

Comment: @Grundy Ну в `ajax` у него объект, потому да именно объекта. И нужна не сортировка, а как раз наоброт, избежать сортировки числовых ключей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в объекте числовые ключи хранятся в упорядоченном виде, потому чтобы ключ не был числовым, достаточно добавить какой-то префик к этому ключу и тогда ключи сохранят свой порядок

**Заранее предупреждаю**, что алгоритм написан исключительно для вашего случая - это значит, что в `JSON`-е в виде строки последовательность вида:

```
кавычки число кавычки двоеточие открывающаяФигурнаяСкобка
```

однозначно определяет ключ и начало его значения. Если где-то ещё, например имени ключа в подобъекте (там где `name`) или в значении свойства в подобъекте (там где `"test число"`) встретится такая же последовательность или ещё где-то, то алгоритм работать не будет и приведёт к неожиданным результатам

Алгоритм:

1. Добавлем префикс (пробел) к числовым ключам, чтобы они не меняли свой порядой при парсинге

   1.1 Во втором аргументе [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) знак `$1` является десятичной цифрой, вставляет 1-ую сопоставившуюся подгруппу из объекта [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) в первом параметре. Более подробно про такие символы можно прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement)
2. Далее мы оборачиваем наш объект в [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), чтобы можно было кастомизировать полчуение значения по имени ключа ([get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get)). Это нам надо чтобы мы могли получить доступ к значению написав ключ как `число` и как `пробел + число`. Например в цикле [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) `key` будет выглядеть как `пробел + число`, а ниже при простом обращении мы просто пишем `число`

Код:

```js
const ajax = '{"3":{"name":"test 3"},"1":{"name":"test 1"},"22":{"name":"test 22"}}';
const modifiedAjax = ajax.replaceAll(/"(\d+)":{/g, '" $1":{');

console.log(modifiedAjax);

const data = new Proxy(JSON.parse(modifiedAjax), {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return prop[0] === ' ' ? target[prop] : target[' ' + prop];
  }
});

for (const key in data) {
  document.querySelector('.list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data[key].name +'<br>');
}

const searchId = "22";

console.log(data[searchId]);
```

```html
<div class="list"></div>
```